# Computing Lebesgue measure of the hypercube intersected with a ball.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, volume

Let $B_\infty = [-1, 1]^n$, and let $B(x, r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x - y\|\ \leq r\}$. I would like to bound (or compute, if possible)

$$
v(x, r) := \lambda(B_\infty \cap B(x, r)) 
$$
as a function of $x \in B_\infty$ and $r > 0$. Above $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Of course, if $r$ is large enough (say $r \geq 1 + \sqrt{n}$), then $B_\infty \cap B(x, r) = B_\infty$, and thus $v(x, r) = 2^n$. So, it is only for somewhat small $r$ say $r \ll \sqrt{n}$, that I would like to get such a bound. The naive estimate would be 
$$
v(x, r) \leq \min\left\{2^n, \frac{r^n\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)}\right\}, 
$$
simply by using the two volumes together. Is this the best possible estimate?

Comment: It also seems clear that $v(x, r)$ is maximized when $x = 0$.

Comment: The notation $B(x,r)$ you are using is confusing. I guess you simply mean $B(r)$? If not then you should check your definition of $B(x,r)$.

Comment: Oops, yes, that is a typo. Thanks for the catch @PhoemueX.

Comment: Are you interested in the case of fixed $n$, and only want to understand the dependency with respect to $x,r$, or do you also want to understand the asymptotic behavior with respect to $n$?

Comment: It would be okay for me to understand just $\sup_x v(x, r)$. I mostly care about the scaling with respect to $r$ and $n$.